# sencha cmd 4 and sencha touch 2.3 adding css in app.json

Tags: css, sencha-touch, themes, sencha-cmd

I have been using Sencha touch 2.3 with Sencha Cmd 3 and there has been no issues.

I recently upgraded to Sencha Cmd 4 and generated a new Sencha Touch 2.3 app.

Now, I tried to change the theme by adding the following in the **app.json** file:

```
"css": [
    {
        "path": "touch/resources/css/cupertino.css",
        "platform": ["chrome", "safari", "ios", "ios-classic", "android", "firefox"]
        "theme": "Cupertino",
        "update": "delta"
    },
],
```

and i removed the previously existing code:

```
{
    "path": "resources/css/app.css",
    "update": "delta"
}
```

This is not reflecting in the app. What is wrong ? This is the approach that is suggested by the docs. But it is just not happening. If i directly place the **cupertino.css** in the **resources/css** path and rename it to **app.css**, it reflects. So where is the **app.css** being set?

Comment: Basically, i just cant add an external CSS via app.json !! What has changed in Sencha Cmd 4 ???

Comment: I am still running the same issue, and though few days ago, I opened similar thread on sencha forums but the solution provided seems not working: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?274253-Sencha-touch-2.3-themes-are-not-installed-by-default&p=1005178#post1005178

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sencha CMD 4 uses the bootstrap.js file to launch the app. Run the **sencha app refresh** command to update the bootstrap.js file with the css properties defined in your app.json file.

Comment: amazing, why isn't this written in 'introduction to theming' tutorial !!

Answer (score 1):

Can you please post your `cupertino.scss` file to make sure that everything is configured in the right way. I faced this issue when i migrated to Sencha Touch 2.3 & CMD4.

Also you don't need to reference the whole path inside app.json

Correct app.json

```
"css": [
    {
        "path": "resources/css/cupertino.css",
        "platform": ["chrome", "safari", "ios", "ios-classic", "android", "firefox"]
        "theme": "Cupertino",
        "update": "delta"
    },
],
```

Correct Cupertino.scss

```
@import 'sencha-touch/cupertino';
@import 'sencha-touch/cupertino/all';
$background-color: #fff !default;
$primary-text-color: $ios7-blue !default;
$secondary-text-color: #000 !default;

@import 'shared';
.charttoolbar {
    .x-button {
        border: 1px solid $ios7-blue;
        background-color: white;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not just with cupertino.css. I was facing this problem with any external css that I wanted to add via app.json. It was not reflecting. But as @jeff pointed out, running sencha app refresh worked!